# cassandra: does/can it return new version ID after insert or update?

Tags: cassandra

Pseudo code:

```
ok, id = cassandra.insert(object,....);
printf("version of inserted object %d\n", id);
ok, id = cassandra.update(object,....);
printf("version of updated object %d\n", id);
ok, id = cassandra.update(object,....);
printf("version of updated object %d\n", id);
```

This is might print:

version of inserted object 1
version of updated object 2
version of updated object 3

Any monotonically increasing datum will work.

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't - it's very hard to do in the distributed system...
Records are versioned by their timestamp, that is set by client by default (in recent versions of drivers).